# Export Excel(XLS) to CSV automatically

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have two excel file `A.XLS` and `B.XLS`. I setup these two files to sync(link) automatically. after syncing the two files. I need to save `B.XLS` as a `CSV` file, in-order to use the data in another application(this app only accept `CSV`).

To save `B.xls` i have to open it every time but i don't want to do this instead i want to create the `csv` of `B` automatically every time when some change is made on `A` OR on `b.XLS`

Please help if there is anyway to do this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use R. Here is a case where I had excel books each with several worksheets of 3 columns of different names, which I renamed to `TIME DATA BY` in my output csv.

```
require(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("book.xlsx")

# loop through worksheets
lst = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb))
dat=data.frame()
for (l in 1:(length(lst)))
{
  # Rename data columns, add to dataframe dat
  s <- data.frame(lst[l])
  names(s) <- c("TIME","DATA","BY")
  dat <- merge(Inverter.dat,s,all = TRUE)
}

write.csv(dat,"wb.csv")
```

Comment: It looks like What am looking for but am a newbie to excel vba and some of the code turn to red? for example `wb <- loadWorkbook("~book.xlsx")` and everyting starting from the `for` loop

Comment: This code will turn a workbook with any number of worksheets into a csv. It is coded so that the number of columns in each csv are set (currently to 3), and are always renamed as 'TIME','DATA', and 'BY' respectively.

Comment: @Hulu This is not a VBA program but an [R](http://www.cran-project.org/) program. You have to install R and run it from there.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut i am getting these error on line one`> wb <- loadWorkbook("book.xlsx")
Error: could not find function `"loadWorkbook"`
> ` Same for "readWorksheet" and `1st` variables

Comment: `@Hulu` You need the XLConnect connect package. I modified my code to reflect that. Install it using `install.packages('XLConnect')`